# Transfer context data from phone call to app

Tags: telephony

Where can I learn different techniques of transferring context data to my app, when someone calls a phone and uses touch tone to make basic choices and I want those choices (context) to be transfered to my app which is attached to a telephone channel.

Answer (score 0):

When a computer system interacts with a phone system, it needs an integration system. This is called Computer Telephony Integration (CTI).

In our instance, transferring context data between a phone and a software application is called first-party CTI.

There is on the market a lot of different CTI solutions, several are quite expensive.
On the standard side, only one standardized protocol remains CSTA from ETSI.
On the API side, you can find several Telephonic API, quite often named TAPI TSAPI ...